# Is there a way I can check for missing links?

Tags: firefox

I'm developing a website using PHP. In my HTML I include some JavaScript and CSS files. I'm using Firefox to test my code. Is there a way using Firefox I can test for CSS and JavaScript that needs to be included but is missing "File does not exists"? Almost like the Find broken images option in the web developer toolbar in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

[LinkChecker](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/532)

Answer (score 0):

It's a stand alone tool but I like the LinkChecker

> LinkChecker is a free, GPL licensed website validator. LinkChecker
>   checks links in web documents or full websites.

http://wummel.github.com/linkchecker/